# Merging two columns but only certain cells?

Tags: vba, excel

Consider a CSV that contains images within a directory. Now for whatever reason, some file names end up in column A and some end up in column B. I'm using command prompt `dir > foo.csv` in a directory to retrieve a list of files.

So it ends up as something like:

```
   A           B

203 foo.jpg
204 bar.jpg
205          345 baz.jpg
206          346 foo1.jpg
204 bar1.jpg
```

So I need to merge cell A & B but only where the image is missing (in column A). It's important that the number in column A be replaced by the number in column B (because I use text to columns after to split the number/file name).

I couldn't figure out a way after an hour besides manually copy/pasting which I refuse to do. It seems simple enough maybe I need another pair of eyes because I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Need for VBA. Put this formula in Cell `C1`

```
=IF(B1<>"",B1,A1)
```

and drag it down. Next Do this.

1. Copy Column C and Paste Special Values on Column C it self.
2. Delete Col A and Col B

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the fast answer. May you explain the `<>`? Thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help :)